# Does $\langle \Omega | \phi(p)\phi(-p)| \Omega\rangle$ in Peskin & Schroeder agree with the Feynman propagator in momentum space (for $m=0$)?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, propagator

In the 2. part of their book Peskin & Schroeder start writing for the 2-point function (here cited for a massless particle, but there is another equation (11.75) where it is given for a particle with non-zero mass):

$$\langle \Omega | \phi(p)\phi(-p)| \Omega\rangle   = \frac{i}{p^2} \tag{p.408}$$

Is this expression equivalent to the momentum space representation of the Feynman propagator $\tilde{D}_F(p)$ earlier (p. 31 below eq. (2.60)) used in this book ?

$$\tilde{D}_F(p)\mid_{m=0} = \frac{i}{p^2-m^2 +i\epsilon}\mid_{m=0}    \tag{p.31} $$

In other words my question is related with the following relation: Is it true or not and if yes why:

$$\int d^4 x e^{ipx} \langle \Omega|T \phi(x)\phi(0)| \Omega\rangle = \langle \Omega | \phi(p)\phi(-p)| \Omega\rangle$$

**complete REEDIT:**

I will develop the problem a little bit so that one can see where it takes me. According to P&S (p. xxi) the 4-dim. Fourier transform is defined as (I suppress here the tilde indicating the FT):

$$\phi(p) = \int e^{ipx} \phi(x) d^4x = \int dt e^{iEt} \int d^3 x \,e^{-i\mathbf{px}} \int \frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3 2 E_\mathbf{k} }(a_\mathbf{k} e^{-ikx} + a^\dagger_\mathbf{k} e^{ikx})$$

For simplicity the following abreviation $E = \sqrt{\mathbf{p}^2 +m^2}$ and parallel with the knowledge $E\equiv E_\mathbf{p}$ is used in the following. The mass $m$ can be set to zero if necessary.

$$\phi(p)=\int d^4x \int (a_\mathbf{k} e^{i(E-k_0)t}e^{i(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{p})x} +a^\dagger_\mathbf{k} e^{i(E+k_0)}e^{-i(\mathbf{p}+\mathbf{k})})\tilde{dk}$$

A further notational simplicity used here is Srednicki's abreviation $\tilde{dk} =\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3  2E_\mathbf{k}}$

We will use the definition of the 4-delta function(see page xxi of P&S):

$$\int d^4x e^{iE_\mathbf{k} t}e^{-i\mathbf{k}\mathbf{x}} = (2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}(k)$$

$$\phi(p)=(2\pi)^4\int (a_\mathbf{k}\delta^{(4)}(p-k)+a^\dagger_\mathbf{k}\delta^{(4)}(p+k))\tilde{dk}$$

If we form the product $\phi(p)\phi(-p)$ we get in total:

$$\phi(p)\phi(-p)=(2\pi)^8\int\!\!\int\tilde{dk}\tilde{dq}(a_\mathbf{k}\delta^{(4)}(p-k)+a^\dagger_\mathbf{k}\delta^{(4)}(p+k))(a_\mathbf{q}\delta^{(4)}(p+q)+a^\dagger_\mathbf{q}\delta^{(4)}(q-p))$$

If now the vacuum expectancy value is taken we get:

$$\langle 0|\phi(p)\phi(-p)|0\rangle = (2\pi)^8\int\!\!\int \tilde{dk}\tilde{dq} \langle 0 | a_\mathbf{k} a^\dagger_\mathbf{q}| 0\rangle \delta^{(4)}(p-k) \delta^{(4)}(q-p)$$

The vacuum expectancy value of the product of creation and annihilation operators can be immediately executed:

$$\langle 0|\phi(p)\phi(-p)|0\rangle = (2\pi)^8\int\!\!\int \tilde{dk}\tilde{dq} (2\pi)^3 (2E_\mathbf{k})\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{q}-\mathbf{k}) \delta^{(4)}(p-k) \delta^{(4)}(q-p)$$

The evaluation of integral yields:

$$\langle 0|\phi(p)\phi(-p)|0\rangle = (2\pi)^8\int\! \tilde{dq}[\delta^{(4)}(p-q)]^2$$

The last expression is highly singular, tentatively I will just assume that under the integral there is just one $\delta$-function and not its square:

$$\langle 0|\phi(p)\phi(-p)|0\rangle \cong (2\pi)^8\int\! \tilde{dq} \delta(E_\mathbf{p} -E_\mathbf{q}) \delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{q}-\mathbf{p})$$

$$\langle 0|\phi(p)\phi(-p)|0\rangle \cong \frac{(2\pi)^5}{2E_\mathbf{p}}\delta(0)  $$

So it seems that some regularisation of the expression $\langle 0|\phi(p)\phi(-p)|0\rangle\,$ is necessary which P&S withholds.
It also seems that the factor $1/2E_\mathbf{p}\,$ could be also the result of a complex integral that is evaluated with the residue theorem. However, in the equality $\langle 0|\phi(p)\phi(-p)|0\rangle = i/p^2$ there is no integral at all. I would like to know at which point the given derivation lacks sense and which kind of regularisation recipe has to be applied in order to get the desired result.

Comment: So the question is about the $i\epsilon$-prescription, not the $Z$-factor? The answer is probably either (i) because of Euclidean signature, or (ii) because P&S forgot/didn't bother to write the $i\epsilon$ explicitly.

Comment: @Qmechanic please my edit.